# How to partition from single drive

Tags: partitioning

I have a new laptop with Ubuntu. I want to have a separate partition in order to install Windows on it.

Currently I have a single partition. When I open GParted, I can't resize it since the min and max size are the same. And I can't unmount it, since it's in use.

What's the best way to create another partition and install Windows on it? I already have the bootable USB with Win11 ISO on it, but somehow I don't have the option to boot from the USB in the BIOS.

Thanks,

Comment: Not an Ubuntu question, so off topic. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic. But drive has to be gpt & best to leave blank space & Windows wants many partitions with UEFI install.

Comment: It's easiest to resize partitions using a *live* system (*thus no file-system on disk is being used*), and booting external media (*regardless of OS but this will include windows*) is device *firmware* specific. I have device(s) that require machine to be off, and me to press & hold a key down which will cause device to turn on & ask if I want to enter uEFI settings or boot external media; ie. how you do it is controlled by your machine *firmware* (and or its settings if configurable), and not a Ubuntu question as it's not involved.

Comment: If you want to dual boot it’s far easier to install Windows first. It will take over the whole disk but when you install Ubuntu it will resize things. Just backup your data and restore when you are finished. It’s not impossible to install Windows second but do your research. You will find it is much harder.